# Android DialogFragmentのImageViewにウェブ上の画像を表示する方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: android, webview, 画像, dialog

Android DialogFragmentのImageViewにウェブ上の画像を表示する方法を教えて下さい。

詳細：
　お世話なっております。
　
　現在、WebViewを使用したアプリを制作しております。
　動作として、ウェブにpng,jpgのリンクがあり、それを押した場合Dialogを開き、その画像を表示したいと思っております。
 以下のコードとレイアウトでダイアログは表示できたのですが、ImageViewにウェブ上の画像を表示する方法が実現できず困っております。

下記サイトを参考に色々試したのですが、アプリが異常終了してしまいます。
http://blog.iscw.jp/?p=658
http://logicalerror.seesaa.net/article/419965567.html

imageview.setImageURI(url)でなくimageview.setImageDrawable(drawable)を使用することがわかったのですがInputStreamで異常がでてしまいます。

レイアウト側でbackgroundに画像を設定した場合は表示されるため構造は間違っていないと思い、色々試しているのですが困っております。
正直な話、ご質問する内容自体が間違っているのかも？と考えてしまうほどです。
InputStreamの問題だけでなく、ImageViewへの動的画像追加もMainActivityで行う必要があるのでは？と思っているのですがダイアログと合わせることが初めてでどのようにすることが正しいのか？で迷っております。

アドバイスを頂ければ幸いです。
よろしくお願いたします。

追記：
下記でご指摘を頂いた部分（エラー時のコード＆Log内容）を追加させていただきました。

TestDialogFragment.java

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class TestDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

private static final String TAG = "TestDialogFragment";
Drawable image = null;


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_setting, null);

builder.setView(content);

String mUrl = getArguments().getString("image_URL");
Log.i(TAG, "Bundle渡されたURLの確認:" + mUrl);

URL url = null;
try {
url = new URL(mUrl);
InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent();
image = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "");
is.close();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imgvi_dialog);
imageView.setImageDrawable(image);

 //ダイアログのボタン設定
 builder.setMessage("画像表示")
        .setNegativeButton("閉じる", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
// User cancelled the dialog
}
});
// Create the AlertDialog object and return it
return builder.create();
}
}
```

dialog_setting.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imgvi_dialog" />
</LinearLayout>
```

エラー内容

```
11-19 05:24:20.955  15316-15316/com.testdialogimage I/TestDialogFragment﹕ Bundle渡されたURL:http://coliss.com/wp-content/uploads-2009/2009073105-01.png
11-19 05:24:20.955  15316-15316/com.testdialogimage W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4137eac8)
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
11-19 05:24:20.965  15316-15316/com.testdialogimage E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1126)
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
        at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:190)
        at java.net.URL.getContent(URL.java:447)
        at com.testdialogimage.TestDialogFragment.onCreateDialog(TestDialogFragment.java:47)
        at android.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:398)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5159)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:815)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:582)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: 例えば*imageview.setImageURI(url)でなくimageview.setImageDrawable(drawable)を使用することがわかった*、*InputStreamで異常*ということですが、肝心のエラー内容やエラーの出ている箇所が何も記載されていないため、いかんとも判断できません。背景説明よりも、エラーとなる処理とエラーメッセージの方を記載していただければ助かります。

Comment: hata様　
ご指摘ありがとうございます。
質問内容に自信が無く曖昧な表現で記載してしまいました。
申し訳ありません。
ご指摘に添うように質問内容を編集させて頂きました。
良ければご意見、アドバイスを頂ければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetworkOnMainThreadException は典型的なエラーで、ネットワークタスクを、UI 用のメインスレッドで実行してしまった時に出るエラーです。Android OS では（古いバージョンでは禁止されていなかったのですが）、ユーザーの操作を受け付けなくなるような、この種のタスクの実行を禁止しています。

提示されたコードでは、

```
URL url = null;
try {
    ...
}

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imgvi_dialog);
imageView.setImageDrawable(image);
```

の部分の処理がそれに当たります。

この禁止事項を回避するには、メイン UI スレッド以外の別のスレッドを作って、そちらで実行すれば問題ありません。実装方法には、2 つの典型的な方法があって、

1. Thread を直接使う
2. AsyncTask を使う（Thread は内部で間接的に使われるが、プログラマー側が意識する必要はない）

です。AsyncTask の方が、ネットで情報は多く、実例が見付かりやすいかもしれません。

---

AsyncTask を使う場合の概略を説明すると、

1. AsyncTask を拡張して Image ダウンロード用のクラス（ex. AsyncImageDownloader）を実装する
2. AsyncTask の中の doInBackground メソッドで、try ブロックまでを処理する
3. AsyncTask の中の onPostExecute メソッドで、ImageView にセットする部分の処理を行う

このように用意した AsyncImageDownloader クラスを使って、

```
(new AsyncImageDownloader(imageView)).execute(mUrl);
```

といったようなスタイルで、呼び出して実行します。

Comment: hata様
ご解答を頂きありがとうございます。
詳細なご説明のおかげで、無事、動作させることができました。
本当に有難うございました。